# Restartable Tasks with timed operation

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I have an issue with cleaning up network-synced objects:
On each tick the server sends the client (Unreliably) the states (Position, Quaternion) of objects around that player.

In order to increase performance on the Client side, I wish to clean (hide or dispose) of objects that are not updated for X time.

I came up with the following idea:

Implement a mechanism similar to JavaScript's `setTimeout`.
The mechanism should support mid-run termination as well as restarting with the same set of args.

I thought of creating a `class` which implements `Task` and accepts `ushort` as timeout interval, and Action/Function to perform after the time had passed.

I will refer to the above class as `TimedTask`.

`TimedTask` would have 2 inner threads/tasks:
1. thread/task1 would be in charge of the sleep until the timeout
2. thread/task2 would be in charge of receiving mid-run commands (for instance, restart, stop, terminate)

The `TimedTask` can live a long time and it depends on the circumstances, and there might be more than 20- 100 `TimedTask`s running in parallel.

I'm afraid the above implementation will cause major performance issues, and there might be a better way to solve this problem, should I loop over each networked object my client has on every tick and see which ones were not updated?

If you guys have any suggestion I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `setTimeout` already exists: just combine `Task.Run` with `await Task.Delay`.

Comment: Why are you wanting to create this? This sounds like [an X/Y problem to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Dai I wish to create this sort of operation, since I have a loop (which runs for eternity - think of it as a game tick loop), which every tick receives data, and there are objects which every tick updated with the above data. In order to preserve resources, I'd like to dispose or hide objects which are no longer updated after a period of time, and if they are updated before that time, I wish to cancel the cleaning operation.

Comment: For gaming/modelling you'd not create "cleanup tasks in the future" but instead simply clean up objects as you go on each update...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so in a case such as this would it be okay, to go over a list of objects and check which is not relevant anymore? wouldn't it be a waste of O(N) operation every tick making it O(N)^2?

Comment: I've edited my question, to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`PauseTokenSource`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/) class by Stephen Toub (also available in the [AsyncEx.Coordination](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/) package by StephenCleary). You could have hundreds of long lived tasks, each one controlled by a separate `PauseTokenSource`. The performance would depend on what you are doing inside each task. The overhead of the pausing mechanism should be negligible, unless you are anticipating a frequency of ~100,000 loops per second or more (for all tasks in total).

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;

async Task CreateLongLivedTask(PauseToken pauseToken, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await pauseToken.WaitWhilePausedAsync(cancellationToken);
        DoImportantStuff();
        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken); // 10 loops per second
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a viable option! Thank you for the knowledge sharing.